# compiler error when declaring constructor function

Tags: c++, constructor, visual-c++-2008

I'm working on my serious c++ program. It's been awhile since I've taken any classes, so I'm a little rusty. When starting the basic implementation of a game loop (After spending freaking FOREVER getting SFML to work), I continually ran into issues. After awhile, I've gotten my list of issues down to an error when trying to define a constructor function. I get the following error when trying to compile.

> 1>game.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall game::game(void)"
>   (??0game@@QAE@XZ) already defined in main.obj
>
> 1>game.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall
>   game::gameLoop(void)" (?gameLoop@game@@QAEXXZ) already defined in
>   main.obj

My code in main is

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "game.cpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

in game.h it's

```
#ifndef _game_h
#define _game_h

class game
{
public:
     game();
    void gameLoop();
};

#endif
```

and in game.cpp it's

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"

game::game()
{
    std::cout << "Constructed thingie";
}

void game::gameLoop()
{
    std::cout << "RAN LOOP!" << std::endl;
}
```

I don't know why I'm running into this error. Any help would be nice as I'd like to get started on my project.

Comment: dont include the .cpp in main

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should include `#include "game.h"` in main, not `game.cpp`.

Comment: That just causes game.cpp to not know what the class game is. Even if I include game.cpp in game.h Not sure how that's supposed to help anything.

--edit--
Nevermind. Including game.h in both main and game.cpp makes it compile for some reason.

Comment: I think you misread, you should not remove game.h from game.cpp, just replace game.cpp in main with game.h

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I just misread it as "move the inclusion of game.h to main.cpp" rather than "include game.h, not game.cpp in main.cpp". It works fine now :) Dunno how to close the question though.